# Delete with aliases on two tables on the same query[Postgres 9.5]

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I'm not sure what is wrong here:

```
DELETE t1 FROM modified_client_config AS t1, modified_client_config AS t2
WHERE t1.Date < t2.Date AND t1.Client = t2.Client AND t1.Server = t2.Server;
```

I search before asking the question and found there was a rule when deleting with aliases:

```
DELETE f FROM dbo.foods AS f WHERE f.name IN (...)
```

So, is that possible to use this syntax with to aliases?

I know it is the same table with the two alias but I imagine my colleague wrote this to delete only when date1 < date2.

Comment: Yes, i was trying to delete the most recent row between each combination of `client` and `server`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you only want to retain the latest row for each combination of `client` and `server`.

You can do that with a co-related sub-select:

```
delete from modified_client_config as t1
where exists (select * 
              from modified_client_config as t2
              where t2.date > t1.date
                and t2.client = t1.client 
                and t2.server = t1.server);
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/LOAN66059